# script in powershell to open and change a value in gpedit (group policy editor)

Tags: powershell, testing, automation, automated-tests

*Hello Everybody !
My question is about creating a script in powershell.
I need an example that shows me how to change a value in gpedit using the power shell. Is to automate the implementation of changes, to increase security.*

**Manually:**

Configure the policy value for Computer Configuration >> Administrative Templates >> Windows Components >> Windows Remote Management (WinRM) >> WinRM Client >> "Disallow Digest authentication" to "Enabled".

**For automatite.**

Registry Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Registry Path: \SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Client\

Value Name: AllowDigest

Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 0

Comment: Can you post the code you've attempted so far and we can assist you with that.

Answer (score 0):

To read the registry value you use:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Client -Name AllowDigest
```

To write/change the registry value to '0' you use:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Client -Name AllowDigest -Value 0
```

Two things to remember:

1. Writing to the registry requires for your PowerShell script to run as an Administrator.
2. The registry path and entry has to be there before you read / write to it, but reading your request you should be good as you are asking how to change the value.